# GWT creating a link to a file on computer

Tags: gwt

```
String link = "file:///c:/test.csv";
Html htmlLink = new HTML("<a href=\"" + link + "\">Download CSV File</a>");
```

I created the above link and I'm adding it to a vertical panel. When I click on the link, nothing happens...Is this the correct way of creating a link to a file on computer?

Answer (score 0):

No, there will be discrepancies depending on OS and browser.

This will explain it all, and if you can achieve what you want:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme

```
Works on windows in FF and Chrome. Doesn't seem to work in IE9.
<a href="file://localhost/C:\test.csv">Download CSV File</a>
```

This work's in IE, as long as your not logged into a domain:

```
Works in IE9, Chrome, and FF on a local account, may not work logged into domain account.
<a href="file:///C:\test.cvs">Download CSV File</a>
```

This will only serve to download a file local to the user through their browser, but why would I download a file already on my machine.

If the file is on your server/machine, then you should make the file accessible on the web server, by way of virtual directory. Then you could do:

```
String link = "/temp/test.csv";
Html htmlLink = new HTML("<a href=\"" + link + "\">Download CSV File</a>");
```

Comment: I"m using windows and I"m using the correct format for windows. Thanks

Comment: Didn't work for me. Did it work for you on a gwt application?

Comment: I did it in an .html file. What HTML is the gwt outputting, IE security prevents the link from being clickable, but you can right click and save as, but I know that is not the desired effect.

Comment: If I use the links in a simple html, then they work but they don't work on a gwt application.

Comment: If you explain what you're trying to do, that can help someone give you the correct answer. If you're trying to use file: in an online app, that may not work.